# Assigning containers host name to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file - kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to add en entry in the `etc/hosts` inside the container as following

```
127.0.0.1 hostname-of-pod
```

and i got this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) which explains how to add an host entry, however i would like to know what we need to add to get that `hostname-of-pod`

Comment: am I right that you would like to know how to get the pod's hostname (the on's you are going to edit /etc/hosts on)? Or you'd like to know the hostnames of the other pods (so your pod will be able accessing these "other" pods?  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append `127.0.0.1 hostname-of-pod` by:

```
Command 1: kubectl exec -n namespace -it pod_name sh
Command 2: echo "127.0.0.1    $HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
```

Note `Command 2` needs to execute inside pod after `command 1` succeed.

Comment: Command  _always_  goes after double hyphen. Without it you'll have `error: you must specify at least one command for the container`

Comment: I have defined `sh` at last man that is the container command.

Comment: Yes, but it is needed to write it as : `kubectl exec -n namespace -it pod_name -- sh` , otherwise, 'sh' is not recognized as a command that shall be ran under container.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the node name or host IP into environment variables in a pod using the downward API

see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables for more info

I believe that the part you were looking for is this:

```
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/565

Answer (score 0):

> however i would like to know what we need to add to get that hostname-of-pod

It should already be in /etc/hosts for Pod. K8s handles it for users.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox-68dc67fcc5-gwd95   1/1     Running   6          6h52m

$ kubectl exec -it busybox-68dc67fcc5-gwd95 -- sh

# cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.60.0.17  busybox-68dc67fcc5-gwd95
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: instead of `127.0.0.1 localhost` i want `127.0.0.1 hostname-of-pod`

Comment: What is the background reason for that? Pods are mortal (normally)

Comment: ok, actually i have a service which needs to run on an `ip address` in a container,also that will be accessed by other containers, so i want the `hosts` file to have the container's `hostname` to be resolved to `127.0.0.1` .

Comment: Pods are communicating via `services` .  Services are tracking the list of active `endPoints` particular App/container runs on. After that traffic from other pods is delivered to particular pod. Container listens particular port and replies back. It looks like you are going to run all your containers on the same Pod am I right?

Comment: In such a case all the other Pods shall access this Pod via `Service`. `/etc/hosts/` is not used for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211553/discussion-between-doc-noob-and-nick).